# How to modify an UIDatePicker's content?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uidatepicker

Is there any way I could change an UIDatePicker's content ? Instead of displaying dates or time, I would like it to diplay names. (and each name would have a return value, ex: if the user picks the name 'Alpha' the picker would return 1, 'Bravo' would return 2, 'Charlie' 3 ect)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use UIPickerView instead.

Comment: Ok. And then how do I proceed ?

Comment: Here is a simple tutorial how to use it: http://www.iphonesdkarticles.com/2009/01/uipickerview-creating-simple-picker.html

Answer (score 0):

You should view the documentation [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPickerView_Class/Reference/UIPickerView.html). It's kind of self explanatory